# ajax, error is called but it work anyway

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I send a post request using ajax, the data is being saved in the database but my success function never run?

If I put the success function in the error function the app is behaving as I would expect. I dont see any error messages in the node terminal. I have built the API myself, but I have noticed any problems before.
I am still on the steep learning curve, is there something wrong I have missed in my code?

```
$('#newPoiForm').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let formData = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/pois/',
        data: formData,
        success: function(message) {
          console.log('success, now run the success function');
          // add the new point ajax should go here
        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log('something went wrong');
          $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/pois/last',
            success: function (data) {
              $(data.features).each(function (key, data) {
                // add last to poi
                  console.log('last point added');
                  poi.addData(data);
                });
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

Comment: Probably because your server doesn't return any valid formated JSON. I guess you have an error in your browser console. Anyway, for testing purpose, remove `dataType: 'json',` and check if success callback is fired

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. Check status and response body to see if it returns what is expected

Comment: callback hell !!!. Avoid nesting ajax

Comment: Also use the error arguments to determine why it goes to error

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, will have a go at it. 
I know there is a callback issue growing here, I just wanted make sure it all worked before I fixed it.

Comment: I removed the dataType as @A.Wolff suggested and then my success function ran.

Comment: It did not actually show error in the browser console before though. The server is not sending json back after the request is send, so I suppose that is the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

first get rid of the nested success function within the error function and replace the error function with this to debug the cause:
error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }

Then have a look at the url, they differ within your success functions.
Either simply the first url-parameter is wrong, or the response is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the debug tips. Oh yeah the url was lazy typing, localhost is not needed.